# How do I do "svn st" in AnkhSVN for Visual Studio? -no text-

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

Just installed AnkhSVN and I see the equivalent of "svn up" but I'd prefer to run "svn st" first so that I don't just blindly update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next release of AnkhSVN will enable the 'Recent Changes' tab in the pending changes window. This allows the equivalent of 'svn st -u' (It shows outgoing and incoming changes).

We are still working on the usability of this view in the 
[daily builds](http://ankhsvn.net/daily/).

Input welcome on the AnkhSVN users list.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pending changes window you can add that will show what files you have changed in your local working copy.  I usually keep it in the set of docked windows where the output window is.  In general, you can also tell what status a file is in by the icon next to the file.  For example, a plus sign means that it's been added.

**UPDATE:**  [Here's](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html#tsvn-dug-general-icons) a guide to the icon overlays.  They should be about the same as in Tortoise SVN.